# How to compare different models configurations

Tags: neural-network, lstm, text-classification, recurrent-neural-network

I am implementing a neural network model for text classification. I am trying different configurations on RNN and lstm neural network.

My question: How to compare these configuration, should I compare the models using the training set accuracy, validation accuracy or testing set accuracy?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I will explain how I finally compared my different RNN models.

First of all, I used my CPU for model training. This will ensure that I get the same model parameters each run as GPU computations are known to be non-deterministic.

Secondly, I used the same tf seed for each run. To make sure that the random variables generated in each run is the same.

Finally, I used my validation accuracy to optimize my hyper-parameters. Each run I used a combination of different parameters until I choose the model with the highest validation accuracy to be my best model.